# Cannot connect to kafka which is outside of network

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my job inside a container which sends events to kafka cluster in another container.
No matter what i've tried, i can't send the event to kafka topic
I 've tried telnet and kafkacat to the address listener port of my kafka, everything works just fine:

[Telnet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUl2u.png)

[Kafkacat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQWMz.png)

This is my job compose file, "172.16.33.91" is my local ip address:

```
version: '3'
services:
    events-processor:
        build:
            context: ./events-processor
        extra_hosts:
            - "host:172.16.33.91"
        restart: unless-stopped
```

This is my job code, which sends data from 1 -> 1000 to a existed topic **num-test**:

```
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

if __name__=="__main__":
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['host:9093'],
                             value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
    for e in range(1000):
        data = {'number' : e}
        producer.send('numtest', value=data)
        print(data)
        sleep(5)
```

This is my kafka-zookeeper compose file:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        volumes:
            - zk-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
            - zk-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
            - secrets:/etc/zookeeper/secrets
        restart: unless-stopped

    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports: 
            - "9093:9093"
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT      
            KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
            KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
        volumes:
            - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
            - secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
        restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
    zk-logs: {}
    zk-data: {}
    kafka-data: {}
    secrets: {}
```

Anyone have any idea what've i done wrong? Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: what do you mean cannot connect? Connection refused? Connection time out? Kafka not receiving anything? What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a better place this information should be put, or keywords you're missing to find the solutions, let the community know

Multiple blogs are written on this already

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,HOST://localhost:9093
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,HOST:PLAINTEXT      
KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,HOST://0.0.0.0:9093
```

1. Using `://:port` address will only listen to the local hostname, container or not
2. You must listen to external connections by *binding* to all interfaces, 0.0.0.0
3. You must *advertise* internally and/or any external hostnames

Answer (score 2):

I remembering encountering a similar issue with connectivity. Turns out, for your container to be able to access the ports on your host machine, you may need to add additional rules to your firewall to open it up.

For example with iptables, you can add a rule like the below to allow your host machine to accept requests from your docker containers.

```
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

Alternatively, you can put your job container on the same docker network as your kafka/zookeeper. Either by putting your application in the same docker-compose file, or using a common external docker network.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Working Sample :

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: zookeeper1
    hostname: zookeeper1
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper1:22888:23888;zookeeper2:22888:23888;zookeeper3:22888:23888"
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    volumes: 
      - ./data/zoo-1/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./data/zoo-1/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  zookeeper2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: zookeeper2
    hostname: zookeeper2
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper1:22888:23888;zookeeper2:22888:23888;zookeeper3:22888:23888"
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
    volumes: 
      - ./data/zoo-2/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./data/zoo-2/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  zookeeper3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: zookeeper3
    hostname: zookeeper3
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper1:22888:23888;zookeeper2:22888:23888;zookeeper3:22888:23888"
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
    volumes: 
      - ./data/zoo-3/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./data/zoo-3/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: kafka1
    hostname: kafka1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
      - zookeeper2
      - zookeeper3
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,OUTSIDE://:9091
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,OUTSIDE://kafka1:9091
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/logs


  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: kafka2
    hostname: kafka2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
      - zookeeper2
      - zookeeper3
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,OUTSIDE://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:29092,OUTSIDE://kafka2:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/logs

  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:$CP_VERSION
    container_name: kafka3
    hostname: kafka3
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
      - zookeeper2
      - zookeeper3
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,OUTSIDE://:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:29092,OUTSIDE://kafka3:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/logs
```

dont forget to edit `/etc/hosts` and the proper hostnames to ba able to work with above kafka cluster outside the `Docker`.

my `/etc/hosts` file is shown below :

```sh
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       kafka1
127.0.0.1       kafka2
127.0.0.1       kafka3
```